# Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. on java & javascript

Tags: java, javascript, serial-port

I have lost hours and hours trying to fix this, but without success, so maybe someone can help me :)

I am using http://www.walking-productions.com/jsserial/new/JSSerial.html for reading data from serial RF-ID reader to automatically fill my text field. I managed to make everything work OK if I make a button and call openport(); and startTimer();.

However if I call openport(); from onload or in any part of my html without a user interaction, I got Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject in that function openport();.

I suppose it is some kind of security feature or some signed java program?

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is there maybe some way to set any browser for to allow this code to start?
thank you
Dorijan